# Execute two sql procedures using same OLE DB Connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oledb

I am using following procedure to run a SQL procedure `dbo.CalcItemCost`.

```vb
Private Sub cmdApplyFilter_Click()
    Dim ItemCode As Variant
    Dim VariantCode As Variant
    ItemCode = Sheets("1-GetItemCost").Range("B3").Value 'Pass value from cell B3 to SellStartDate variable
    VariantCode = Sheets("1-GetItemCost").Range("B4").Value
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CalcItemCostConnection").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "EXEC dbo.CalcItemCost '" & ItemCode & "','" & VariantCode & "'"
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CalcItemCostConnection").Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

The procedure is running absolutely fine and showing the results in excel sheet "1-GetItemCost" starting from cell `A7`. The parameters `ItemCode` & `VariantCode` which needs to be passed to procedure `dbo.CalcItemCost` are specified in cells B3 & B4 Respectively.

Now, I need to run another SQL procedure naming `dbo.CalcItemCost_Detailed` in which I wish to pass same parameters i.e. `ItemCode` and `VariantCode` to be picked from cells `B3` and `B4` and display the recordset starting from cell `A15` as shown in below image of my Excel sheet.

[image]

Can anybody help me in executing above task? Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using calling your second SP with same connection? If so, what was the issue? If not, give it a try and post your updated code and results here

Comment: Dear Zac, 
Thanks for your advice. I have tried and it has been done. I am unable to upload the updated code due to limit of characters in this comment box. But i have just called the second SP with same connection and it worked. Thanks once again.

Comment: It sounds like your issue is resolved. If so, you can answer your own question and accept it so that this query can be closed